# Como retornar o valor ordenado do arsort para variáveis?

Tags: php

Bom, minha duvida é como retornar o valor contido dentro do "arsort($array);" em variáveis que possam ser utilizadas em outras partes do código. mas as mesmas estando ordenadas como o resultado que aparece no "var_dump" tipo: $1 = 5, $2 = 10, $3 = 26, $4 = 34. Já tentei de varias maneiras, mas como sou novato no php, posso estar fazendo errado! Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

```
$num1 = 10;

$num2 = 5;

$num3 = 34;

$num4 = 26;


$array = array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4);

arsort($array);

var_dump($array);

//Código que aparece quando chamado o var_dump

array(4) {

[2]=> string(1) "5"

[1]=> string(2) "10"

[4]=> string(2) "26" 

[3]=> string(2) "34"

}
```

Comment: Você tentou fazer um foreach para percorrer a array??

Comment: foreach($array as $valor){
echo $valor."<br>";
}

Comment: Sim, utilizei. Mas tem como retornar o valor individual de cada resultado para uma variável diferente? ou como modificar o foreach para as variáveis? Provavelmente não estou sabendo fazer

Comment: sim você pode numerar as variaveis, usando um $i++, ou então você pode criar um array para cada variavel...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$num1 = 10;

$num2 = 5;

$num3 = 34;

$num4 = 26;


$array = array($num1, $num2, $num3, $num4);

$sort = arsort($array);

$nova_array = array();
$i = 0

foreach($sort as $value) {
    $nova_array[$i] = $value;
    $i++;
}

//Agora você pode usar assim:

echo $nova_array[0]; // imprime 5

echo $nova_array[1]; // imprime 10
```